# Генерация qr-кода с действиями

Tags: android, qr

Здравствуйте.  У меня есть задача, нужно генерировать qr-код для Android приложения, которое выложено на play market, но нужно генерировать так чтоб при сканировании данного qr-кода открывался play market с данным приложением. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать? ну или линки на примеры, если они существуют.  Зарание спасибо.

Comment: Есть пример qr-кода который делает то-же самое для другого приложения например? Расшифруй его и посмотри что там. Скорее всего какое-то волшебное слово и указатель на приложение в маркете (uuid наверное).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте qr код, в котором будет ссылка следующего вида

```
market://details?id=com.example.your.package
```

`com.example.your.package` - это имя Вашего пакета, Вы его должны знать. Если что, его всегда можно подсмотреть, если открыть googleplay страничку с приложением и внимательно посмотреть в урл.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать